# EWS error when running from WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to access my email using EWS. It is working fine from a Console application. But when I'm trying to access same piece of code using WCF service it is giving me error:

> *When making a request as an account that does not have a mailbox, you must specify the mailbox primary SMTP address for any distinguished folder Ids*

#### Here is my code :

```
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
        service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("username", "password");
        service.TraceEnabled = true;
        service.AutodiscoverUrl("emailID");

        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(
        WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,
        new ItemView(10));
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

#### Edit 1: I'm calling this WCF service from a WP7 app and here is the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig setting

```xml
    <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITestService" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://MachineIP/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ITestService" contract="ServiceReference1.ITestService"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_ITestService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: what identity is the WCF service call running under?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm new to WCF and as per my understanding I think Identity should be in ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file in My APP. I have updated my question with that details. But I don't see any Identity node there. Please let me know where I need to set this Identity.

Comment: Thanks Mitch for your guidance. I read thorough the service Impersonation and able to fix it. Below I'm posting my answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my service method I disable Impersonation and it got fixed

`[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.NotAllowed)]`